# Customization of LengthMenu in language property of Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, css, razor

I developed a page with a datatable, where I customized lengthMenu property and changed "Show [10] entries" to "Display [10] per page" by using below code.

But I want to replace Dropdown arrow by a popup arrow. Please help me if anybody knows the solution. Please look into the image.

```js
$('#MyDataTable').DataTable({
"language": {
            "lengthMenu": "Display _MENU_ Per Page"            
            }
 });
```

[Please Click Here to See Existing drop-down menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jsiis.jpg)

[Please Click Here to See what I Want, a popup menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCQTp.jpg)

Comment: what's your question? You want to change arrow type? Than please show us your html and css

Comment: Yes. I want change arrow type. I did not customize any css or html.

Comment: i think this is because of the theme you are using, or css of datatable, because by default its dropdown, and when you use css from some theme then it has some different styles